# How create .bin file for my Dataset folder?

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have dataset that contain

```
dataset/
 
---> name1--->1.jpg,2.jpg

---> name2--->1.jpg,2,jpg

---> name3--->1.jpg,2.jpg
```

i have to make binary folder as `dataset.bin`

Comment: `binary file` can means anything - `jpg` is also `binary file`, and `xls` is also `binary file`. You didn't say what program/module will use it. Different programs may need different  `binary file` - with different structure - and they may have special tools for this.

Comment: sir, i want to make my dataset similar like lfw.bin or vgg2_fp.bin. what should i do?